# Плохо работает SDL_Event на нескольких окнах

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, sdl2

Когда я обрабатываю несколько окон SDL2, то на них не работает кнопка выхода. Использую:

```
SDL_Event e;
                    //...
SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS,&win1,&ren1);
                        SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS,&win2,&ren2);
                        SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_WIDTH,SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS,&ball,&renB);
                        SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_WIDTH,SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS,&ex,&renE);
                        SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(SCREEN_WIDTH*3,SCREEN_WIDTH*2,SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS,&score,&renC);
                    //...

                    bool run=0;
                    while(run){
                        SDL_PollEvent(&e);
                        if(e.type==SDL_QUIT)run=0;
                    }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обрабатывать событие выхода на нескольких окнах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем [мануал](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType#Remarks):

> An `SDL_QUIT` event is generated when the user clicks on the close button of the last existing window.

Это не баг, а фича.

Вам нужен [`SDL_WINDOWEVENT`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent) с `.window.event ==`[`SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEventID).